# JSLint error "Unexpected Var"

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint keeps giving me the following error whenever defining 2 functions:

> Problem at line __ character _: Unexpected 'var'.

I have tried declaring all vars at the beginning of the script but this does not solve the issue. Tried digging through the web for an answer but cannot seem to find one.

```
var walk = function walker(node, func) {
    //code
}

var disp= function display(){
    //code
    return d;
}
```

Comment: JSLint may be complaining about the missing `semi-colons`

Comment: you don't need to add a function name when you just placed it in a variable. the variable serves as it's name.

Comment: JSHint tells you to - http://www.jshint.com/reports/215010

Comment: Answers and comments here indicate that you need semicolons after the declarations in order to make JSHint happy. You say in a comment that you *have* those semicolons. Can you please edit the question so that it reflects what you *really* have? Otherwise, I'll have no choice but to close this question as too-localized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try declaring them like this:

```
var walker = function (node, func) {
    //code
};
var display = function () {
    //code
    return d;
};
```

The problem with:

```
var walk = function walker(node, func) {
    //code
};
```

is JSLint expects `walk` to be either assigned a function or the result of the function. If you want to assign a function to the variable, the variable name becomes an alias of the function. To make JSLint happy, it should be an anonymous function.

Comment: Perhaps, but the question is how to make JSLint happy with it. Modified language in answer.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a semicolon after the first declaration.

Comment: sorry, the actual code does have the semicolon after the first declaration- missed it when copying over

Comment: @user1243918 Perhaps you would edit your question to reflect that? There seems to be some confusion here as to what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var walk = function(node, func) {
    //code
};

var disp = function(){
    //code
    return d;
};
```

In JavaScript, your function is a variable with name that you used on the left side of the assignment.

Comment: @Xander However, declaring named functions doesn't result in a function object being returned, hence placing it on the right side of an assignment doesn't help.